# onActivityResult not called after calling GoogleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent()

Tags: android, google-app-engine, cloud, endpoints

I've been following Google's tutorial for an App Engine connected Android project and I'm getting stuck on [this page](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addauth).

Specifically in section 8c there seems to be an error. As stated in the title, the onActivityResult method is not called in the following code.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Start up RegisterActivity right away
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,"server:client_id:" + WEB_CLIENT_ID);
    startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    System.out.println("onCreate finished");
    //new EndpointsTask().execute(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
        if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {

            accountName = data.getExtras().getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            if (accountName != null) {
                credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                new EndpointsTask().execute(getApplicationContext());
            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

Everything has been going well up until this point when I noticed that the AsyncTask isn't being executed and nothing ends up in the Datastore in the GAE console.

Is anyone aware of this problem and maybe point me in the right direction? I've been at this for hours and all I can think is there is a problem with the other activity not setting the "resultCode"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it seems to me that the reason why the onResultActivity() method does not called since you start activity before it which is the registration activity. I believe that you need to put this method credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,"server:client_id:" + WEB_CLIENT_ID);
    startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER); in the registration activity you started it using this  startActivity(intent);

Comment: Ok guys thanks for pointing out to me that I've got another activity starting right before I get the credentials. I've got tunnel vision on this tutorial right now. I'm still having trouble but at least now the onActivityResult method is being called.

Comment: You shouldn't start an activity and then continue adding more code in `onCreate`. You must figure another way to do `startActivity(intent)`

Answer (score 2):

You are starting two Activities: `RegisterActivity` and the Google account chooser activity simultaneously. The `RegisterActivity` is called in such a way that it will never trigger return to your `onActivityResult()` function.

So, the first thing you have to do is change this:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

To this:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_REGISTER);
```

*You will have to create the new request `REQUEST_REGISTER`*.

This is because `startActivity()` never triggers return to `onActivityResult()`. Only `startActivityForResult()` does that. This is just the way Android works.

Secondly, I find it odd that both Activities are started simultaneously. You have to look very closely at the logic of why this is being done. I strongly suspect that you *want to* start the two Activities sequentially. I don't know which one should go first.

Start the first one in `onCreate()` as you are already doing (but make sure to use `startActivityForResult()` if it is `RegisterActivity`).

Start the second Activity in `onActivityResult()` if the `REQUEST_*` `requestCode` matches up with the `requestCode` sent to `startActivityForResult()` for the first Activity.

This may fix your problem allowing both the Google Account Chooser, the Registration, and return to your Activity to work correctly.